# Count the frequency of occurence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
Company_ID  Priority
1               1
1              10
1               1
1              10
2               1
3               1
3               1
4               1
8               1
```

I have the above table(similar) in my DB, I need to count the frequency of occurrence of the Company Ids where priority = 1.

i.e. Expected Results,

```
Frequency   NoOfCompanies
1               3
2               2
```

3 companies have priority 1 recorded 3 times. 2 companies have priority 1 recorded 2 times.

I have the query I tried and didnt want to confuse with all the joins I have. The above is a simplified version so that it is easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets make some test data:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    Company_ID  int,
    Priority    int
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
( Company_ID, Priority )
VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 10),
(1, 1),
(1, 10),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(3, 1),
(4, 1),
(8, 1);
```

Now lets see the frequency of each company:

```
SELECT Company_ID, Priority, COUNT(*) AS Frequency FROM @MyTable
GROUP BY Company_ID, Priority
```

Output:

```
Company_ID  Priority    Frequency
1   1   2
2   1   1
3   1   2
4   1   1
8   1   1
1   10  2
```

Now lets see the count of each frequency:

```
SELECT Frequency, COUNT(d.Company_ID) NoOfCompanies FROM
(
SELECT Company_ID, Priority, COUNT(*) AS Frequency FROM @MyTable
GROUP BY Company_ID, Priority
) d
GROUP BY Frequency
```

Output:

```
Frequency   NoOfCompanies
1   3
2   3
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to aggregate your data twice:

```
SELECT Frequency, COUNT(*) NoOfCompanies
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) Frequency
  FROM Companies
  WHERE Priority = 1
  GROUP BY Company_ID
) Frequencies
GROUP BY Frequency
ORDER BY Frequency
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9b52/2)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it in DB2:

WITH topPriority
 AS (SELECT Company_ID FROM table WHERE priority = 1)

SELECT Company_ID, COUNT(*) FROM topPriority GROUP BY Company_ID

Edit: Someone was faster...